# Cisco command wont work on syxtax checker

Tags: cisco, access-control-list, ios, command, syntax

I'm trying to validate the building of a tool for managing Cisco ACL commands.

Thing is i'm using the aclcheck sintax validator (i dont own cisco equipament) with the following command do check

```
access-list 101 permit udp host 192.10.05.233 EQ 80 host 225.193.43.235 EQ 80
```

My previous question helped me to correct errors in my tool but as far as i`ve researched this command should be right. A source host, source port, destination host and destination port filter, right?

OBS: Don`t bother about the addresses, they are just hypothetical, my tool only has to generate cisco commands in the right syxtax.

Regards,

Comment: http://techie.devnull.cz/aclcheck/ posting the URL of the software i`m using just in case you guys need some reference.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is valid, however this access-list will rarely be useful. You typically just want to specify the destination port as requests will use a random source port for each connection. Try this:

> access-list 101 permit udp host 192.168.10.05.233 host 255.193.43.235 eq 80

That will allow connections with any source port with a destination port of 80.

As far as not having any cisco equipment, if you can get your hands on an IOS image you can emulate it with GNS3 http://www.gns3.net/

Comment: Yeah i know... weird that the syntax checker does`nt get it :S.

Thanks for the tip of GNS3... that would be a awesome addition for demonstrating my project... too bad i got no time left for this.

Final presentation is Saturday. Are you sure my command runs on IOS then? It it what i need to know so i can defend my project.

Thanks again!

Comment: That command is perfectly valid

Answer (score -2):

One thing that looks strange to me about the ACL is the UDP / port combo.  Port 80 is implicity a TCP port.  The effect of this ACL after considering the implicit deny any any is that all TCP port 80 traffic will be blocked if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: ... No.  There aren't any implicitly TCP or UDP port numbers.  Is there a well-known application on TCP/80?  Yep.  Does that mean nothing can happen on UDP/80?  No.